# The value is sent to system call function, don't match with the valid system call code

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, system-calls

When I was investigating in an executable file,I reached to the piece of code below:

```
MOV EAX,11B9  
MOV EDX,7FFE0300  
CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EDX]  
RETN 10
```

This is used to demand a system call. Until here, there is no problem.

I searched within the whole system call code of Windows OS, but none of them is equal to 11B9 in the instruction in the first row "MOV EAX,11B9".

Could everybody guide me, what it means here exactly?

Comment: `ret 10` is really weird; that's not a multiple of 4.  Is this function called with some 16-bit push instructions or something?  Oh, I guess all your numbers are hex but you left out a `0x` prefix or `h` suffix.

Comment: I copied the whole code from Olly debugger.yes, the numbers are in hex,but my concern here is not for the instruction ret 10! I got confused by the 11B9 system call value.

Answer (score 1):

Syscalls numbered 0x1XXX are calls to win32k.sys.

[Here](https://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/win32k/64/) is a great table created and updated by j00ru showing the win32k syscall IDs for different versions of Windows: